# How to migrate Nexus to Artifactory ? Any manual or automation process steps ?

Tags: artifactory

Migration steps from nexus to Artifactory (local, remote, virtual )

-> manual steps or automation ?

Answer (score 16):

We have [a tool](https://github.com/JFrogDev/nexus2artifactory) for that :) Welcome!

Comment: Thanks for the response , can you please elaborate :)

Comment: Well, you follow the link, download the tool, and follow the instructions. Did you try to run it, and ran into some problems?